# how to remove add button for previous cloned div?

Tags: jquery, html

actually I am cloning div using clone method when I clone it is appending entire along with add and remove buttons but I need show when I **click** on add button it should clone entire div with add and remove button but it should not show add button for previous cloned `div`.

How to solve this?? somebody help me..

**Below is HTML code..**

```
<div class="wid100 cf1">
    <div class="group1 nopl"><label>Company :</label> <input type="text" class="company_name" name="company[]" required="required" /></div>
    <div class="group1 nopl"><label>Experience (Yrs) From:</label> <input type="date" class="experience_1" id="filevalidation" name="experience1[]" required="required" /></div>
    <div class="group1 nopl"><label>To:</label> <input type="date" id="filevalidation"  class="experience_2" name="experience2[]" required="required" /></div>
    <label>Roles & Responsibilities :</label> <textarea rows="6" class="job" name="job_description[]" required="required" ></textarea>
    <div class="add2">+</div><div class="remove2">-</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery code,**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.remove2').hide();

 var count = 1;
  $(".add2").click(function() {

  if(count<5){
    count++;

    $(".cf1:first").clone(true).insertAfter(".cf1:last");
    $(".cf1:last").find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    $(".cf1:last").find('input[type="date"]').val('');
    $(".cf1:last").find("textarea[name=job_description]").val('');
    $(".add2:last").closest(".add2").remove();
    $(".remove2:last").show('');
   }
   else{
    $(this).closest(".add2").remove();    
     count--;
   } 
});

$(".remove2").click(function() {
    if(count>1){
    $('.cf1:last').remove();
     count--;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You can achieve it by hiding $(".cf1:last .add2").hide(); inside your click event

Comment: @ Mohtisham it is not working.

Comment: Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/j6sg854c/1/ there we can solve this issue

Comment: Looks like you just one guy chatting with himself. Like Matt and Mathew. :P

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/j6sg854c/5/

Comment: @zer00ne  lols .............. . Indeed quite similar names

Answer (score 0):

I update fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j6sg854c/5/) now add button is not adding

```
$(".cf1:last .add2").hide();
```

inside your click event